# Substracting two datetime.time columns in data frame

Tags: python, pandas, datetime

There is data frame df with two columns with datetime.time objects like this:

```
  TimeA           TimeB
  00:50:13        00:50:00
  00:51:46        00:50:00
  00:52:58        00:50:00
  00:54:05        00:51:00
```

I want to create third column with differnce between these two. Elements in columns are datetime.time objects. First I tried on single values below method:

```
>from datetime import datetime, date, time
>TimeA = datetime.combine(datetime.min, df.iloc[0,0]) - datetime.min
>TimeB = datetime.combine(datetime.min, df.iloc[0,1]) - datetime.min
> diff = TimeA - TimeB
```

It gives below result:

```
datetime.timedelta(0, 13)
```

However, when I try to convert whole column :

```
df['TimeA_2'] = df['TimeA'].apply(lambda x : datetime.combine(date.min, x) - datetime.min)
```

below error occurs:

```
combine() argument 2 must be datetime.time, not float
```

It doesn't make sense, beacuse when I check type of elements in both columns, they are datetime.time. 
I have no idea, where is the error. Would be very grateful for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can convert your columns to `datetime` objects, then take the difference and convert to minutes:

```
import numpy as np

df[['TimeA', 'TimeB']] = df[['TimeA', 'TimeB']].apply(pd.to_datetime)

#                 TimeA               TimeB
# 0 2018-03-05 00:50:13 2018-03-05 00:50:00
# 1 2018-03-05 00:51:46 2018-03-05 00:50:00
# 2 2018-03-05 00:52:58 2018-03-05 00:50:00
# 3 2018-03-05 00:54:05 2018-03-05 00:51:00

df['Diff'] = (df['TimeA'] - df['TimeB']) / np.timedelta64(1, 'm')

#                 TimeA               TimeB      Diff
# 0 2018-03-05 00:50:13 2018-03-05 00:50:00  0.216667
# 1 2018-03-05 00:51:46 2018-03-05 00:50:00  1.766667
# 2 2018-03-05 00:52:58 2018-03-05 00:50:00  2.966667
# 3 2018-03-05 00:54:05 2018-03-05 00:51:00  3.083333
```

Answer (score 2):

IIUC use `pd.to_timedelta`:

```
df[['TimeA','TimeB']] = df[['TimeA','TimeB']].apply(pd.to_timedelta)
df['Diff'] = (df['TimeA'] - df['TimeB'])
```

Output:

```
     TimeA    TimeB     Diff
0 00:50:13 00:50:00 00:00:13
1 00:51:46 00:50:00 00:01:46
2 00:52:58 00:50:00 00:02:58
3 00:54:05 00:51:00 00:03:05
```

OR

```
df['Diff'] = (df['TimeA'] - df['TimeB']).dt.total_seconds() / 60
```

Output:

```
     TimeA    TimeB      Diff
0 00:50:13 00:50:00  0.216667
1 00:51:46 00:50:00  1.766667
2 00:52:58 00:50:00  2.966667
3 00:54:05 00:51:00  3.083333
```